# Expresso Store: customer registration

Tags: expresso-store

I'm looking for any suggestions what to use (addons) to have ability to:

- create customer account during checkout process (as an option)
- capture customer data (billing and shipping address)
- store all completed orders

and if account exists:

- let clustomer to log in
- use stored data (billing and shipping address) during checkout process
- view all completed orders

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest and free approach would be to use Freemember, also created by Expresso. It offers member registration tags within templates and integrates nicely with Store, allowing you to map custom member fields to Store customer/order fields.

If you need your member profiles to be a bit more complicated, you can use something like Zoo Visitor, which provides similar functionality, with the addition of connecting member profiles to channel entries so any channel fieldtype can be used.

In either case, you can align your user's flow through the site to register and then direct over to templates with your cart and checkout using the return="" parameters on the registration tags.

Comment: I have checked Freemember addon, but cannot find any information how to store customer data (shipping/billing address) into a member profile

Comment: Well, it looks like for complex data capture I need go for Zoo Visitor.

Comment: Shipping/billing address information can be stored in custom member fields (native EE functionality), and accessed from Freemember's tags. I just did this on a site a couple months ago.

Comment: I will try that option before I will go for Zoo Visitor. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to create the member fields which you are mapping the Store & FreeMember data for by going to Members (in the top navigation bar) > Member Fields > Create a New Field. Then in your Store settings for Member fields you will need to map the data to the fields you just created.

Answer (score 2):

To create a user account during checkout you can use the register_member='yes' parameter on the exp:store:checkout tag or submit a register_member field:

https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#register_member_yes